# ResolvePrincipal returns SPPrincipalInfo with PrincipalId == -1

Tags: spprincipal

When/why does SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal return a non-null SPPrincipalInfo with a PrincipalId of -1 ?
I can manually assign rights to the user through the web interface.
The user resides in an active directory.
If I request a non existing user null is being returned as expected.
The same logic works for a lot of other users.

```
SPPrincipalInfo principalInfo = SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal(currentWeb, objectPrincipal, SPPrincipalType.All, SPPrincipalSource.All, null, false);
if (principalInfo == null)
{
  result[i][j] = "Can not determine principalInfo for name: " + objectPrincipal;
  continue;
}
if (principalInfo.PrincipalId <= 0)
{
  result[i][j] = "Got invalid PrincipalId: " + principalInfo.PrincipalId + " in principalInfo for name: " + objectPrincipal;
  continue;
}
```

My log output:

Setting rights failed for user: DOMAIN\usr1 error: Got invalid PrincipalId: -1 in principalInfo for name: DOMAIN\usr1

Any ideas?

Comment: Edit: after manually adding the rights for the user it wont return a PrincipalId of -1 for this user in the future. So it seems like I just need a way to do this "lazy user initialization" via code somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When null is returned the user does not exist, when PrincipalId -1 is returned I have now used the EnsureUser method to make the existing user known to the sharepoint system.